# Vue Storybook doesn't compile with Pug components

Tags: vue.js, pug, storybook

I am trying to add storybook to my project, which written using pug. Unfortunately, storybook stops to compile if I create story with component on pug. If I change template lang to html (and template itself), all works just fine.

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue last night when adding storybook to an existing Vue/Pug project.
Storybook supports extending it's webpack config.

First open the file `.storybook/main.js` in your project directory.
Here you can add a function for `webpackFinal` to the object, which received the webpack config as an argument, and u can push additional loaders into the rules.

More info here in the storybook docs:
https://storybook.js.org/docs/vue/configure/webpack

Here is my file where i have added pug and sass support:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  "stories": [
    "../src/**/*.stories.mdx",
    "../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)"
  ],
  "addons": [
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials"
  ],
  webpackFinal: async (config, { configType }) => {
    // `configType` has a value of 'DEVELOPMENT' or 'PRODUCTION'
    // You can change the configuration based on that.
    // 'PRODUCTION' is used when building the static version of storybook.

    // Make whatever fine-grained changes you need
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.scss$/,
      use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../'),
    });

    config.module.rules.push(
      {
        test: /\.pug$/,
        use: [
          { loader: 'pug-plain-loader' }
        ]
      }
    );

    // Return the altered config
    return config;
  },
}
```